How should I ask permission for using tables or figures from published papers, in my own paper?
If I find myself in a situation where I want to incorporate a table or figure from a previously published paper into my own manuscript, and I am unable to modify the content of that table or figure in any way, I need to know the proper procedure for requesting permission. Specifically, I would like to understand how to approach a journal or the original author of the published work to obtain the necessary authorization to use their tables or figures in my own research paper. What steps should I take to ensure that my request is clear, respectful, and compliant with copyright regulations?

In almost all journals, you will find a link on the article page that will allow you request to permissions (see screenshot from a Wiley journal). Depending on the copy right settings of each article, the process to obtain permission will be different and the requests from the copyright holder as to what you have to write on the reproduced figure or table will vary as well. But normally you click on the link and the system will guide you through the process.
For some open access publications, it is enough to state the open access license that is given at the article, and you do not actively have to ask for permission to reproduce. But in those cases I would always check the extent of the open access and what it permits, as there are differences.


You need to ask the copyright holder, which may be the author(s) or the publisher. If you start with the author it might be easier to navigate, but they may not be able to actually give permission. They can, if needed, point you to the publisher.
You can also start with the web site of the publisher which may have the information about the path to follow and who to ask, perhaps.
There is no special etiquette for asking other than being clear. Giving a sentence or two about your own work, especially if it is an extension might be useful.
